# Installing build-essentials with linux-headers package

Tags: linux, installation, debian, aptitude

I'm trying to update the network card drivers on my Debian based server. I'm following this guide: [Driver installation guide](http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Installation_des_r8168-Treibers/en#Installation_from_source)

I reached the step
`` aptitude install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` ``
 however I installed the linux-headers package first like so
`` aptitude install linux-headers-`uname -r` ``

Now, I'm trying to install the build-essential package but is seems to require me to remove the newly installed linux-headers package. Here's what I get: [installation message](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7145963/)

How can I resolve these dependancies?

Answer (score 0):

<del>Can you rephrase your question? You're saying you already did `` aptitude install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` `` so why are you trying to install build-essential again anyway? Did something go wrong the first time? Did something go wrong when executing that command?</del>

A lot of that seems to be because it's wanting to install up to date versions of the compiler etc. but you currently have older versions of libraries.  Try updating everything first (note that if the kernel version changes you'll have to install the newer kernel-headers, also.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I just rephrased it.

Comment: I did a full apt-get update & apt-get upgrade before that. Is that what you meant by updating?